# NSTextField - make selected text bold, italic or underline?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField where the user can write text. I would like to be able to make 3 buttons: bold, italic and underline; these buttons should change the user selection in the textfield to either bold, italic or underline.

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing is to enable rich text support, and you can do it either in Interface Builder by checking the "Rich Text" option in the inspector or by code using `setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:`.

Then it's all about `NSAttributedString`s.

The big problem though is that looks like you need to apply changes to the selected text. This is not possible with `NSTextField`s. Only with `NSTextView`s.

If you can change it, go ahead and it will make things easier. However, if you do need to stick with `NSTextField` you may want to access the field editor. Each window has one associated, and it's what process the text behind the scenes.

```
NSTextView *editor = (NSTextView *)[window fieldEditor:YES forObject:myTextField]
```

Then you can call NSTextView's method `setSelectedTextAttributes:` happily.

Read more about the field editor [here at Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001815) and [in CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FieldEditor)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your NSTextfield * is *textField*, the code below underlines the selection:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * as = [[[textField attributedStringValue] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[as beginEditing];
[as addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
           value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
           range:[[[textField window] fieldEditor:YES forObject:textField] selectedRange]];

[as endEditing];
[textField setAttributedStringValue:as];
```

Comment: But that underlines the first three characters, not the selection. (Also, why not use `[[[textField attributedStringValue] mutableCopy] autorelease]`?) I wonder, could you ask the field editor what the selection is?

Comment: i actually found a simple solution.. sorry for being late. What I did was adding  a font manager to my app in IB and then assign a format-panel to the NSMenu (the on in the very top of all mac apps), then i connected the bold menu item to the font manager (recieved action: addFontTrait:) and now it works.

Comment: now i only need to make my core data accept an NSAttributedString instead of an normal NSString.. hmm :-) There is no datatype for Attributed string in the core data entity editor..

Comment: Alternatively you can using bindings for ( bold / italic) for the given text field by setting the model key path variable to be a bool type with the value true.