# Make selected string of text view Bold, Italic, Underline like native "Notes" app of iOS

Tags: ios, swift, textkit

Is there any help to make selected string of text view Bold, Italic, Underline like native "Notes" app of iOS. Please give me helpful links. I am tired of searching for the whole day. Many Thanks.

I have attached my code, to make attributed string Bold and Italic both like native app of iPhone "Notes".

```
attributedString.beginEditing()
attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(app_delegate.settings.chatFontSize))], range: range)
attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(app_delegate.settings.chatFontSize))], range: range)
attributedString.endEditing()
```

But its giving only Italic string, not also Bold. I need both Italic and Bold. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861756/nstextfield-make-selected-text-bold-italic-or-underline?rq=1

Comment: @ElTomato both links not working. Please provide some helpful solution.

Comment: @LeoDabus Please check. I have attached my code. Thanks.

Comment: @AdeelIshaq What Xcode/Swift version are you using? You should tag your question accordingly

Comment: @LeoDabus  Xcode 9.0 , Swift 3.2

Comment: @LeoDabus It was old project. I did't convert into 4.0.

Comment: @LeoDabus do you thing my code is fine? its issue with language version?

Comment: @LeoDabus both have same ranges. Do you have idea of Text Kit? Please check Notes app by assigning different fonts to same selected string.

Answer (score 9):

The problem in your code is that you are setting the italic font and overwriting the bold one you've just set. What you need is to use  `UIFontDescriptor` with Symbolic Traits as you can see in this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21777132/2303865). So just initialize your system font, get its font descriptor and add traitBold and traitItalic to it. Then you just need to initialize your new Font using UIFont initializer `init(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor, size pointSize: CGFloat)`:

**Swift 4 code:**

```
attributedString.beginEditing()
let systemFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 32)
if let descriptor = systemFont.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits([.traitBold, .traitItalic]) {
    let systemFontBoldAndItalic = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 32)
    attributedString.addAttributes([.font: systemFontBoldAndItalic, .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
}
attributedString.endEditing()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `NSAttributedString`. You can use that to create strings that have mixed attributes at different ranges.

In Objective-C, the mutable version, `NSMutableAttributedString` has methods like `setAttributes(_:range:)` that let you change the attributes of an attributed string in a specified range.

So you'd initialize an NSMutableAttributedString starting from a normal String object, and then use `setAttributes(_:range:)` function to set different attributes like Bold, Italic, etc on a range of the string.

(No, I don't have sample code handy.)

Comment: I know this thing alread. For specific range, you can set bold or italic font.

Comment: But my question is, how can we set more than one font for fix range?

Comment: Any given character can only be a single font. Are you asking how you can set multiple attributes, like bold underline? You simply pass a dictionary to `setAttributes(_:range:)` that contains more than one attribute, like

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old but it may helps someone.

Using `NSMutableAttributedString` won't solve the problem, because if you type any where before the customised text the range will be different. Therefore, the customisation will shift to satisfy the updated range.
I think using HTML is better solution if you would have a very long string.
You may consider using some open source libraries, like [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor)
Hope that help.

Comment: I have done this feature without using HTML editor. :)

Comment: This only happens if you don't know how to edit your string attributes properly. You can simply enumerate your text attributes and keep all other properties intact.