# Where is italics and bold in NSMutableAttributedString (Xcode)?

Tags: swift, nsmutableattributedstring, italics

I have a large string and I want parts of it to be in italics or bold. I have successfully used `NSMutableAttributedString` to change certain properties. See below:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Testing Bold")
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 5))
    testlabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

But I can't find anything called italics or bold in the dropdown menu of attribute choices. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to set a font with the desired bold and/or italic attributes.

Comment: Could you please show with some example code :) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070670/2303865